# Unable to Archive the project while able to Run it - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, runtime, archive

I am facing a complicated issue that, i am not able to archive my project. But when i run it, everything is all right.

While on indexing resources it says archive/build failed and does not continue anymore.

How to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Likely a provisioning profile issue.  Those are very irritating.  More info is needed to resolve that one.

Comment: @StevenOjo the issue is i am not getting an error,

Comment: @Putz1103 what info else do you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try opening Build Log Navigator and try to see the error.